# jQuery UI drag and drop closer items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm currently using jQuery UI to make a drag and drop in my application.
I'm using it to make a game, where you need to make combinaisons of object (ex: a bottle of beer with lighter)

But in some case items are closer so if I drag and drop, the drop event handle multiple times..

There is a way to make the handle just happen one time ? Or detect only the closest object on multiple hover ?

**EDIT**

Code :

```
$('#overlay-objet img').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: _.bind(function(event, ui) {
        object = $(event.target);
        if (object.attr("data-val") != undefined){
            objectDrag = object.attr('data-val').toString();
            objectDrop = $(ui.draggable).attr('data-val').toString();
            object.addClass('hidden');
        $('#'+object.attr('data-toggle')).removeClass('hidden');
        this.dragDropEvent(objectDrag + objectDrop);
        }
    }, this),
    over: _.bind(function(event,ui){
        object = $(event.target);
    object.addClass('hidden');
        $('#'+object.attr('data-toggle')).removeClass('hidden');
    }, this),
    out: _.bind(function(event,ui){
        object = $(event.target);
    object.removeClass('hidden');
    $('#'+object.attr('data-toggle')).addClass('hidden');
    }, this) // Edit mercredi soir ajouter ,this dans chaque callback
});
$('img.big-objet').draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
```

I didn't say it above but i'm using backbone + requireJS + underscore

Answer (score 0):

Without your code we can barely help you. Anyway I can guess what's going on there. You probably don't use `this` keyword in your `drop` function and using a query selector.
Look at my code here:

#### HTML

```
  <div class="draggable">Drag me</div>
  <div class="droppable">Drop Here</div>
  <div class="droppable">Drop Here</div>
  <div class="droppable">Drop Here</div> 
  <div class="droppable">Drop Here</div>
```

#### JS

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
  helper: 'clone'
});
$('.droppable').droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

This works fine. Look at jsbin page [here](http://jsbin.com/amused/). 
But if I use a selector instead of `this`, then drop can impact all the elements that selector match. Think if I write the code like this:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
  helper: 'clone'
});
$('.droppable').droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui){
    $('.droppable').css('color', 'red'); // selector instead of this
  }
});
```

Then it [will not work](http://jsbin.com/amused/2) as supposed